# I am trying to create new button in C# but i think my syntax is not proper

Tags: c#, wpf, button

So this is my Syntax in the bottom, actually i am making a app launcher, whenever I'll select an exe file it will create a new launch button for it but after running this code i am not getting any response at all, i tried looking the code for making new button but it was same.
This is my code

```
private void AddNewAppBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Functions.addApp();
    Button appButton = new Button();
    appButton.Content = "Click Me";
    appButton.Name = "ButtonA";
    var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
    stackPanel.Children.Add(appButton);
}
```

Comment: Where is the StackPanel used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't added your `Stackpanel` to your main `Grid` or other layout that you want to have the dynamically created `Stackpanel`. First give your main `Grid` a name like this:

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid">
```

Then add this line at the end of your code:

```
mainGrid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
```

Comment: How did you figures this out from the code provided?

Comment: @R.Rusev Obviously the OP has created the `StackPanel` dynamically. So it is not a children of his main layout.

Comment: But he hasn't shown the entire code of the function so you can't be sure of that. Although I assume that you are right.

Comment: @R.Rusev I really cannot imagine any other state.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the button inside the XAML, no code-behind. By doing this and only this, you can implement the MVVM pattern which make your maintainment will less pain.

XAML code:
`<Button Content="MyButton"></Button>`

Or you want to create a button on cs file. It should be added on your main grid.